# Please upgrade your Copilot extension to continue using this service

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, updates, github-copilot

Today I tried to use the copilot, but suddenly this error start appearing:

```
[INFO] [fetch] [2022-05-19T21:00:55.452Z] Please upgrade your Copilot extension to continue using this service.
```

I tried to uninstall and install again and reload, but nothing happens, anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

There's an error description in the image below:

[image: Error image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the error here instead of providing a screenshot.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This can be resolved by upgrading VSCode itself: Help → Check for Updates / Install Available Updates.

You may or may not need to re-install the extension and re-authenticate with git.

Reference: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/15684

Answer (score 3):

In my case (on a mac) I had to do the following:

- Move Visual Studio Code from Downloads to Applications
- Restart
- Update Visual Studio Code
- Sign into Github
- Open extensions and locate Github CoPilot
- Click "Reload Required"

Comment: It worked! I just wasn't able to update the VS CODE version before the restart, so swap stages 2 and 3

Comment: Thanks @YosiLeibman, I've swapped those around.

Answer (score 2):

1. As @emragins suggested, go to Help and check for updates/restart to update
2. Once you are back on VS Code check if the Co-pilot is activated.

If it is not activated/still gives the same error.

1. Search for **co-pilot** in VS Code **extensions search**
2. Click on co-pilot extension in the search results, you should see **restart/reload required**.
3. **Reload** and it should be working now. If not try closing VS Code and opening it now.

Answer (score 1):

You should uninstall the extension and download the latest version from this page in the form of VSIX file. After that you can install the extension from that VSIX file.

I think it is because there is some API changes and the latest version of the extension. However, it is still marked as preview. When we click on install from the built-in extension browser, it just install the latest stable version.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot

Answer (score 1):

if you are on a linux device, update your vscode first then update your co pilot extension it will work.